# Trying to shift over horizontal menu bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

I'm doing some work on [this site](http://cbebp.co.uk/) and I've been trying to get the menu at the top centered.
The relevant CSS for the site is [here](http://cbebp.co.uk/sites/all/themes/pixture_reloaded/sf/css/superfish.css?C) and, as you can probably see, the highlighting of the menu is weird and the arrow on the side of the dropdown moves when hovered over.
What I did to shift it was:

Override this:

```
#superfish-inner .menu, #superfish-inner .menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

to this:

```
#superfish-inner .menu, #superfish-inner .menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 18px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

and this:

```
#superfish-inner .menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  width: 15em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
```

to this:

```
#superfish-inner .menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  width: 8.4em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
```

I didn't design the site originally and I'm very much not a CSS expert so I was wondering if anyone could point me to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
#superfish-inner .menu li:hover {
    background: none;
    visibility: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It hasn't fixed the arrow but it has fixed the weird background selection thing :)

Comment: find  this class 
"a > .sf-sub-indicator" and remove background-position from it

Comment: Removed so that it now looks like:
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
  top: .8em;
}

but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

(btw, my changes won't be showing up in the external CSS 'cause I'm having to put them in as overrides)